# Dealing with Misleading questions and answers

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do with Q&A's like this which are ill composed, inaccurate and contain full of half truths](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41/what-to-do-with-qas-like-this-which-are-ill-composed-inaccurate-and-contain-f)

This is in reference to the following question:

[Theory behind Linear Predictive Coding (LPC)](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2435/theory-behind-linear-predictive-coding)

but it is also applicable to other questions with the same tone.

The question itself is completely false assumptions and notions. This cannot be appropriately answered. And to the point that answer itself after a long discussion returns a question back saying *To answer your final question, I'm not sure what you're asking entirely.*

We must avoid questions based on false premises. How do you handle this?

Comment: This is mostly the same discussion as the linked question. Also, the question you've referenced is barely a day old and the OP is a frequent user of this site and has responded in the comments and shown a willingness to discuss. I suggest exploring those options first.

Comment: I am Glad there is already consensus here. But there is no action on the said question though.

Comment: I see no effort to illuminate as to what's wrong/how it can be improved either. 6 users have found it useful and only 1 has voted to close... if you want action, you'll have to make a very good case — not to the mods, but to your fellow users.

Comment: Can you elaborate why you think the question is misleading? It is asking "what is the theory behind X?", which seems fairly valid. In what sense is that making false assumptions/notions?